# php's pecl - oauth - Mac OS X 10.6.6

Tags: macos, mac, php, pecl

I'm trying to install a php extension through pecl and I'm getting some weird errors... any ideas?

```
wcmisdpilotpc1:~ alexus$ sudo pecl install oauth
Password:

Notice: Array to string conversion in PEAR/REST/10.php on line 85

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in PEAR/REST/10.php on line 88

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/REST/10.php on line 88

Fatal error: Cannot use string offset as an array in /usr/lib/php/PEAR/REST/10.php on line 256
wcmisdpilotpc1:~ alexus$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting PHP errors, and I believe those are coming directly from PEAR itself, not the extension you are trying to download.

You could always try [installing the extension manually](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.installation.php#mongo.installation.manual).